# Will apt update run every time in my docker build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile and its fifth line is

```
RUN apt update -y
```

Suppose those first five lines will not change in future builds. Only lines below will change.

**Question**

When I build this image later again and again,

- Will the `apt update` run  again (so producing changing versions of packages, ending with an undeterministic result) or...
- Thanks to the layered filesystem changes,  up to the layer created after this line it will be reused from the cache?

Comment: Yes. Think of the Dockerfile as a shell script -- when you 'execute' `docker build` it runs the commands.  You will get `apt`'s state _from build time_ which is generally exactly what you want.   Caching locally can in fact get in the way, so you can say `docker build --no-cache` too.

Comment: Note that Debian and Ubuntu tend to only keep the current version of the `.deb` files in their archives.  This means that using a cached APT index won't use fixed versions of packages so much as lead to HTTP 404 Not Found errors when you try to use it.  You should generally `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install` in the same `RUN` line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The layer generated by the `RUN apt update -y` command is cached and the command will not run again unless the cache is invalidated, which can happen in a number of different ways:

- You explicitly disable the cache by using the `--no-cache` option.
- You modify parts of your Dockerfile that precede the `apt update` line.
- You update the base image (e.g. via `docker pull` or `docker build --pull`).
- Your `Dockerfile` copies a file into the image that has changed since the last time the image was built.

Comment: many thx. I do not understand what is last use case (Your Dockerfile copies...)

Comment: Using for example the Dockerfile `COPY` directive; it's the principal way to copy source code and other things from the host system into your image.  Docker keeps a hash of the `COPY`ed file content, and if the files change, it invalidates the cache.